# Преобразовать массив по формуле

Tags: c++

Нужно преобразовать массив по формуле b(i) = (a(i) - a(i-1))/i
В теории, мой код должен работаь, но что то не так.

```
~~~cpp
void v()//
{
    cout << "\nПреобразовать массив по формуле: b(i) = (a(i) - a(i-1))/i";
    int n = 0;
    int *mass;
    int *mass1;
    mass = new int[n];
    mass1 = new int[0];
    mass[0] = 0;
    cout << "\nВведите количество элементов массива: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\nВведите элементы массива: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            mass1[j] = (mass[i] - mass[i - 1]) / i;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j << n; j++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << mass1[j];
    }

}
~~~
```

Comment: `mass1 = new int[0];` `mass = new int[n];` ??? Куда вы записываете? `mass[0] = 0;` А потом еще циклом перебираете.

Comment: Не до конца понимаю

Comment: У вас указатели на массивы под 0 элементов, причем оба! Присмотритесь к коду, вы выделяете память под 0 элементов. Выделяйте память после того как получите размер массива. т.е. после `cin >> n;` Ну и еще у вас утечка памяти, вы ее не освобождаете.

Comment: Переместил под ```cpp cin >> n; ``` и результата не дало

Comment: А теперь разберитесь с делением на 0.

Comment: ```mass[0] = 0;``` А это разве не для этого сделано?

Comment: Вы меня не поняли: [Деление на ноль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C) Читайте от `В информатике`. И еще, у вас во втором массиве мусор, и 0 элементов.

Comment: Увидел. Спасибо. Но неужели проблема в формуле по которой нужно преобразовать массив?

Comment: @pow3rFluff, расставьте комментарии в коде. Где и что вы делаете. Желательно к каждой строке. Раз вы уверенны, что в теории код должен работать, то вы должны понимать, в какой строке кода что происходит. Когда вы это сделаете, то, скорее всего, сами увидите массу проблем в своем коде.

Comment: Второй цикл по j тут не в тему: `for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)`. Почему вы это делаете много раз?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку исправлять странный двойной цикл нереально, с нуля - примерно так:

```
void v()//
{
    cout << "\nПреобразовать массив по формуле: b(i) = (a(i) - a(i-1))/i";
    int n = 0;
    cout << "\nВведите количество элементов массива: ";
    cin >> n;

    int *mass  = new int[n];
    int *mass1 = new int[n];

    cout << "\nВведите элементы массива: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> mass[i];
        if (i > 0)
            mass1[i] = (mass[i] - mass[i-1])/i;
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)   // b(0) НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЕН!!!!!
    {
        cout << "\n" << mass1[j];
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что, согласно вашей формуле, `b(0)` - не определено! его просто нет, в результате в `mass1[0]` - просто мусор.

P.S. А забавный у вас цикл - `for (int j = 0; j << n; j++)` - вы его реально так и писали?...

Comment: Ахаха, видимо 20 часов без сна дают о себе знать